# Fails to run Gruntfile.js in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gruntjs, task-runner-explorer

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 I am unable to load my gruntfile.js. When I open "Task Runner Explorer" and try to refresh the gruntfile.js it writes the following in my output window:

Failed to run "(PATH)\Gruntfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c grunt -b "(PATH)" --gruntfile "(PATH)\Gruntfile.js" --tasks "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\TaskRunnerExplorer\Scripts" vs-grunt-task-reader

Any ideas?

Comment: Spot on @spender! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you deleted/moved/lost your nodejs packages, so they'll need reinstalling.

Run `npm install` from the command line in the folder that contains `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I had a syntax error in the gruntfile.js but how was I suppose to know grunt did not tell me anything. I restored the grunt file and it worked.