# Gruntfile won't load after Visual Studio update 15.8

Tags: visual-studio-2017, gruntjs, task-runner-explorer

I updated Visual Studio to 15.8, and now I have the following error when trying to compile my less files using Task Runner Explorer:

```
Failed to run "C:\Projects\TFS Git Repo\Main\src\Ljmu.Web.UI\Gruntfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c grunt -b "C:\Projects\TFS Git Repo\Main\src\Ljmu.Web.UI" --gruntfile "C:\Projects\TFS Git Repo\Main\src\Ljmu.Web.UI\Gruntfile.js" --tasks "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\web tools\taskrunnerexplorer\Scripts" vs-grunt-task-reader
grunt[10096]: src\node_contextify.cc:631: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 00007FF677EB82F5 
 2: 00007FF677E94156 
 3: 00007FF677E94221 
 4: 00007FF677E6A69A 
 5: 00007FF6784B5EB2 
 6: 00007FF6784B7008 
 7: 00007FF6784B636D 
 8: 00007FF6784B628B 
 9: 00000292D50841C1
```

Any ideas welcome...

**Edit**

It works fine when running from the command line so I think it's just an issue with Task Runner Explorer.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752647/fails-to-run-gruntfile-js-in-visual-studio-2015-update-2?rq=1)?

Comment: Yep thanks, should have added that I've since updated node.js, totally removed my node_modules folder and ran npm install again. That's when I noticed running grunt from command line worked. I've reported it to VS feedback so we' ll just have to wait and see I guess! @RobC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem happens because the Visual Studio [gulp](/questions/tagged/gulp) is *outdated*.

**Solution:**
Add the updated [node](/questions/tagged/node) to Visual Studio paths:

```
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools
```

Then you need to add your [node](/questions/tagged/node) install directory to the top of the list, like so:

[Node Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGzbJ.png)

This solved my problem.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnMS2.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, and thank you for providing me with the solution. Great first answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the same problem after updating to Visual Studio 15.8

Running the below command in the same directory as my `package.json` seemed to fix the issue for me

`npm install gulp`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for my Task Runner Explorer issue:

In Visual Studio, navigate to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> External Web Tools
```

Move the **$(PATH)** entry above the **$(VSInstalledExternalTools)**.

Hit Refresh on your Task Runner Explorer